# Problem with getting data to go into an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

So for this program, the mean and median are supposed to calculated and displayed but I do not think the data I am inputting is getting put into the array because it runs without error but does not display any data I have put into it.

```
public static double Mean(double[] gradeArray, int numGrades) {
    double totalArray = 0.0;
    double mean;
    for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
        totalArray = gradeArray[i] + totalArray;
    }

    mean = totalArray / numGrades;
    return mean;
}

public static double Median(double[] gradeArray, int numGrades) {
    double median;
    Arrays.sort(gradeArray, 0, numGrades);
    if (numGrades % 2 == 0) {
        median = ((gradeArray[(numGrades / 2)] + gradeArray[(numGrades / 2 + 1)]) / 2);
    } else {
        median = gradeArray[(numGrades / 2)];
    }
    return median;
}
   private void Enter_Grades_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double[] totalArray = new double[25];
    String text_box_input_str = null;
    double text_box_input_num = 0;
    int numGrades = 0;
    String num_grades_str;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0##");

    do {
        try {
            text_box_input_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Item Price", "Enter Price", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (text_box_input_str == null || text_box_input_str.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            if (text_box_input_num > 0) {
                double[] gradeArray = null;
                gradeArray[numGrades] = text_box_input_num;
                numGrades++;
                num_grades_str = Integer.toString(numGrades);
                num_grades_text.setText(num_grades_str);
                Mean_Text.setText(df.format(Mean(gradeArray, numGrades)));
                Median_Text.setText(df.format(Median(gradeArray, numGrades)));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException caught");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Must Input numeric data!", "Bad Data!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } while (text_box_input_str != null && !text_box_input_str.isEmpty());


}
```

I expect the program to calculate the data that is inputted and calculate the mean and median and then display the totals

Answer (score 0):

it looks like text_box_input_num is set to 0, never updated, but then there is an if check if it's > 0

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pointing out the problem with your code directly, I'll give some pointers on how to find it yourself.

1. break your code down into smaller parts
2. for each part, write both the method and the tests that prove the method does what you expect
3. once the individual parts are working, write the method (and tests) that use them.

You'll end up with several methods with names like `getValues`, `hasValue`, `printError`, `checkValidValue`, `showMedian` etc. all of which do exactly what you want.

I guarantee that if you do that it'll become pretty clear very quickly what's wrong.